# Improve Review Tools for Duplicates to Check if a Link is in the Question

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

I just posted this question: [Have two Claims Identities in the User (ClaimsPrincipal) with Only One Used for [Authorize]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61397909/have-two-claims-identities-in-the-user-claimsprincipal-with-only-one-used-for) .  Fairly quickly it got a close vote for being a duplicate.

The question linked to as "Original" to my duplicate, is one that I had already linked to in my question.  (And posted sample code of how it did not work for me.)

Though I think that the person casting the close vote could have been more careful here, I think that the tooling could have easily been setup to help them out.

When the "close voter" picks the question that is the "already existing" question, I don't think it would be too hard to scan the original question for any links to that question or its answers.

If found, a nice red message could be shown, saying: "**The asker has linked to this question already.  Are you sure this is a duplicate?**" (or something like that).

I don't know if this happens often enough to make a feature like this worth while, but I thought I would post it and let those that read it decide.

Comment: I like the idea...but I've also seen questions that say "I want to do X, I looked at <question about X> and it didn't help". Yet, I know for sure that the question explains *exactly* what they need. Either they didn't really read it or they looked at it but just want somebody else to write the code for their set of variables and data.

Comment: @VLAZ - I agree.  That is why it is just a notification.  An "Are you sure?" question to the "close voter" that they don't even have to answer.  Just a bit more information for the voter to see and maybe say"oh, they linked this question?  Maybe I should take a closer look."  (Or if it is a situation like you indicated, hit the close button.)

Comment: @VLAZ _explains **exactly** what they need_ can easily become subjective. If OP couldn't figure it out, but already acknowledged or references the related post then doesn't that constitute _well researched_, and now their issue must be so specific that it should be easy for us as a community to help them. If the dup post was really old they are not likely to get much feedback if they post follow-up questions, and we don't want to encourage them to do this because it will likely become a discussion.